# How to use ArrayFormula with a formula that references different row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a GoogleSheet document that automatically populates new rows based on a webhook from Zapier, because of this I want to automatically fill out any newly created rows with the correct formulas which I believe require the use of the ArrayFormula function as opposed to a normal function.

All I would like to do, is for a new cell in the range to check if the previous cell is the same. I can do this easily with a normal function, but it breaks when I try to use the ArrayFormula.

There is an example of both the normal function (which is working fine) and the ArrayFormula function in the sample sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TCgOA-1VQX63qCobbu6zJg1dF6j0UKTO8Va4oBejiMY/edit?usp=sharing

The ArrayFormula version

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"ArrayFormula Change Test",IF(ISBLANK(A:A),"",if(A2<>A1,"Change "&A2))))
```

My issue seems to be with the part below.

```
... if(A2<>A1,"Change "&A2) ...
```

A quick snap shot of the sheet I'm playing with for clarity:
[Google Sheet Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w36j.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You have `=ArrayFormula(if(row(A1:A)=1,"ArrayFormula Change Test",if(row(A1:A)=2,"",if(A1:A="","",if(HLOOKUP(A1,A1:A,ROW(A1:A),0)<>iferror(HLOOKUP(A1,A1:A,ROW(A1:A)-1,0),""),"Change "&HLOOKUP(A1,A1:A,ROW(A1:A),0),"")))))` in your sheet which apears to work, can you explain why this doesn't suit your requirements?

Comment: Term of using array and refer to different row we have `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN()` to limit rows so it won't endlessly add rows and break the file. And for automation use `COUNTA(A:A)` to tell which row to stop